# How Is The Correct Way To Use CLI Command In Codeigniter 4 To Execute Controller

Tags: php, command-line-interface, codeigniter-4

I have a problem when using CLI command In codeigniter 4. I want to call or execute controller from CLI codeigniter 4.

I have a controller file and folder structure :

**Edit :**

> mywebapp\app\Controllers\ExportAlert.php

And this is the Code inside ExportAlert.php :

```
  <?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;


class ExportAlert extends Controller
{   

    function __construct()
    {
            

    }
    

    public function index()
    {   
                
    }



    public function ExportAlert() { 
        if ($this->request->isCLI()) { 
            echo "Ok"; } 
        else { 
            echo "Not allowed"; 
        }                           
    
    }


    
}
```

And My Folder Structure :

[image]

I try to execute the CLI command :

```
E:\Codeigniter4\mywebapp>php public/index.php ExportAlert ExportAlert
```

And it return :

---

ERROR: 404 Controller or its method is not found: ExportAlert::ExportAlert

---

What I have missing in here ? How is the correct way to use CLI command to call a controller in codeigniter 4 ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

first:

remove index.php in url
go to  app/config/app.php

public $indexPage = '';

second:

app/confi/authload.php
call you modules like me

````
<?php

namespace Config;

use CodeIgniter\Config\AutoloadConfig;

/**
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 * AUTOLOADER CONFIGURATION
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * This file defines the namespaces and class maps so the Autoloader
 * can find the files as needed.
 *
 * NOTE: If you use an identical key in $psr4 or $classmap, then
 * the values in this file will overwrite the framework's values.
 */
class Autoload extends AutoloadConfig
{
    /**
     * -------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Namespaces
     * -------------------------------------------------------------------
     * This maps the locations of any namespaces in your application to
     * their location on the file system. These are used by the autoloader
     * to locate files the first time they have been instantiated.
     *
     * The '/app' and '/system' directories are already mapped for you.
     * you may change the name of the 'App' namespace if you wish,
     * but this should be done prior to creating any namespaced classes,
     * else you will need to modify all of those classes for this to work.
     *
     * Prototype:
     *```
     *   $psr4 = [
     *       'CodeIgniter' => SYSTEMPATH,
     *       'App'           => APPPATH
     *   ];
     *```
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    public $psr4 = [
        APP_NAMESPACE => APPPATH, // For custom app namespace
        'Config' => APPPATH . 'Config',
        'Modules\Shared' => ROOTPATH . 'module/shared',
        'Modules\Common' => ROOTPATH . 'module/common',
        'Modules\Auth' => ROOTPATH . 'module/auth',
        'Modules\Home' => ROOTPATH . 'module/home',
        'Modules\Payment' => ROOTPATH . 'module/payment',
    ];

    /**
     * -------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Class Map
     * -------------------------------------------------------------------
     * The class map provides a map of class names and their exact
     * location on the drive. Classes loaded in this manner will have
     * slightly faster performance because they will not have to be
     * searched for within one or more directories as they would if they
     * were being autoloaded through a namespace.
     *
     * Prototype:
     *```
     *   $classmap = [
     *       'MyClass'   => '/path/to/class/file.php'
     *   ];
     *```
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    public $classmap = [];

    /**
     * -------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Files
     * -------------------------------------------------------------------
     * The files array provides a list of paths to __non-class__ files
     * that will be autoloaded. This can be useful for bootstrap operations
     * or for loading functions.
     *
     * Prototype:
     * ```
     *      $files = [
     *           '/path/to/my/file.php',
     *    ];
     * ```
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    public $files = [];
}
````

Answer (score 0):

There are few changes you need to make here:
First, it extends to Controller and Not BaseController.

So replace BaseController use statement with use `CodeIgniter\Controller;`

Second, you do not need routes defined for this. So remove them.

```
php index.php ExportAlert ExportAlert
```

should be

```
php public/index.php ExportAlert ExportAlert
```

Also, you haven't defined anything in the body so for testing try to enter some data on CLI using CLI's write method.

Comment: Still not working, Is it need to set something ?

Comment: Can you upload the question with the updated code and the commands you are running?

Comment: Could you check again. I have Update the code. Thank You

Comment: This will not work. Your file should be in Controllers folder not in a subfolder within Controllers. Your path should be :  mywebapp\app\Controllers\ExportAlert.php

Comment: Also, for the namespace adjust accordling. Remember Codeigniter can only detect Controllers from the Controllers folder directly.

Comment: I moved the ExportAlert.php to Controller folder and not in subfolder. Then I try run "php public/index.php ExportAlert ExportAlert. But still get same error : Controller or its method is not found: ExportAlert::ExportAlert . What should I do ?

Comment: I also change the namespace to : namespace App\Controllers;

Comment: Can you include the screenshot of the folder structure that you have for your project? Also, can you update your questions with the changes you did?

Comment: Please check again. I have update my post and add the screenshot. Thank You

Comment: Is your project within Daastrading4 folder?

Comment: Yes. It is in daastrading4 folder indeed. And "mywebapp" is just an other name I put.

Comment: I don't find any issue on the code itself. It should work fine. It may be related to windows specific. Try to change the name of the method to something else for testing purpose. Also, as a last resort you can just make it like other API's and mention  a route in your routes file. And then using CURL you can hit that URL. Just make sure your set_timeout is 0 and you have a token that it can check for validation.

Answer (score 0):

I use Codeigniter 4.1.1 with [myth-auth module](https://github.com/lonnieezell/myth-auth). controller works if I access through url, but not from CLI. Then I try to find out in Codeigniter with the same version (have not been use) and I try to access controller from CLI, it works. So I think there is because of the module that we set and we can't handle.